# 'pd.read_csv' reading columns in my csv files as . .

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the 'pd.read_csv' function to read my csv files which contains:

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xND3O.png)

Could I have some suggestions so that the output will display the movie title instead of three dots?

My code:

```
movie_titles=pd.read_csv('movies.csv', sep=',')
print(movie_titles.head())
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EutY5.png)

Comment: Instead of posting the screenshot, paste the output in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have a lot of space left to show the entire details its doing that so you can always print all the columns in your dataframe/CSV by

`movie_titles.columns.values`

Or you can see the column values you want to by just usign

`movie_titles['column name']`

Comment: Ah, I see, the '...' is because there's not enough space to show all the details. I was just curious because I thought I wouldn't be able to display values in that column at all or use it for this movie recommendation system that I am coding up. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for column in movie_titles:
    print(movie_titles[column])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
movie_titles=pd.read_csv('movies.csv', sep=',')
print(movie_titles.title.head())
```

title is the header of movies title in your csv file

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to confirm that I wanted all the columns to be printed out, but I understand that there is too much information to be displayed. Thank you very much for your answer!